# How can I point my custom virtual host server name to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: laravel, apache, localhost, ubuntu-20.04

I've been trying to set up a basic Laravel project with the virtual host server name `lsapp.dev`, and currently when I enter `localhost` in my web browser, it sends me to the desired page, but when I enter `lsapp.dev`, it says the site cannot be reached. Here's my sites-enabled file `lsapp.dev.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin connmoo@gmail.com
        ServerName lsapp.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lsapp/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And I've included this line in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   lsapp.dev localhost
```

At this point, both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` successfully direct me to my site, whereas `lsapp.dev` does not.

Comment: Your first step should be determining if it's a DNS issue or not. A simple ping test will tell you that.

Comment: Have you restart your server?

Comment: @FilipKoblański I have restarted the server.

Comment: @miken32 Thanks, yes I have run a ping test and everything is working fine. Also, when I `curl` it, I get the html that I'm expecting. The only place it breaks down is in the browser.